# How to change brackground color of ngx scrollbar

Tags: css, angular, scrollbar

I have a little bit problem with the background color of my  ngx scrollbar. I not able   to change the background color.I have tried  modify  the css file but this method doesn't work. I leave here  a stackblitz  for example. [enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-scrollbar-v4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Somebody can help me?. I remember that in angular that are a command for change a class in absolute way something like this ":: ngclass " but I m not sure.

Comment: check my answer below.

Comment: In your example if you open home.css you can see the example there.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the scroll bar color or the color of the container of the scroll bars? You could change it by modifying the following variables

```css
ng-scrollbar {
  --scrollbar-color: black;               /* scroll bars background color */
  --scrollbar-thumb-color: yellow;        /* scroll bar color */
  --scrollbar-thumb-hover-color: red;     /* scroll bar hover color */
  --scrollbar-container-color: green;     /* scroll bars container color */
}
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-scrollbar-v4-tqthlj)

Answer (score 0):

Use css like given below :-

```
ng-scrollbar {
  --scrollbar-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've worked around and found the working solution. Use the below code snippet to change background color for ngx-perfect-scrollbar (also on hover).

In css/scss,

```css
::ng-deep .scroll-container {
    .ps__thumb-y, .ps__rail-y:hover > .ps__thumb-y {
        background-color: #209e91;
    }
}
```

In html,

```html
    <perfect-scrollbar #perfectScrollBar [config]="config" class="scroll-container" fxFlex="auto" [scrollIndicators]="true"(psYReachStart)="onScrollEvent($event)" 
        (psScrollDown)="onScrollEvent($event)" (psScrollY)="onScrollEvent($event)">
        ...
    </perfect-scrollbar>
```

[Horizontal ngx-perfect-scrollbar with custom background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPHIp.png)